Sorting lists of strings, based on the order of already sorted lists of strings - Python
I'm trying to figure out a way to sort lists of strings (i.e. ['North Abutment', 'Southwest Embankment', 'Road over structure looking south', 'Spall in northeast wingwall',....]) based on the order of lists I have already sorted. Basically I think I want some sort of neural network that I can feed a large number of already sorted lists into, so that it can learn the proper way to order the strings, so that I can then feed unsorted lists into it and it will sort them for me.
The purpose is, I inspect bridges and take a lot of pictures of similarly named items. I need to provide a report with all the site photos ordered in a specific order. In the past, I have sorted them manually, which takes a long time. I want a program that can take a list of strings (the names of my pictures) and sort them into an order that closest matches the orders of other reports that I did manually in the past.
My lists will vary in length as some sites have more photos than others. Also the strings may not be exactly the same at each site. If there's a really unique item that doesn't match any of the sorted lists items, it can just be added at the end of the sorted list.
ChatGPT was semi-helpful but as usual, couldn't finish the job, and unfortunately this neural network stuff seems to be over my head so what do you real people think?
Initially, I tried pulling out a unique keyword from all the possible picture names I could think I might encounter. Then I assigned a value to those keywords based on where in the order I wanted them to be. I had modifiers for directional keywords (i.e. "North Abutment" always comes before "South Abutment"). This method worked fairly well, but I found that the number of possible picture names kept growing and it was becoming too much work to manually assign an order. So since I have many already sorted lists from the past, I figured I could get a neural network to learn the order and then I could use that trained model to sort future lists. However, I don't really understand the code behind neural networks and chatgpt is not helping at this point.
